# RichTextBox Font Changes when the string contains some Japanese text - C#

Tags: c#

I insert some result strings into my RichTextBox, but there is a small problem. The font will change after some Japanese text and I do not know why!

I tried the FontChanged event but it will not raise.
I know I can Select all the text and change the selected text font in TextChanged event but I do not want to do this. because I should do it so many times which I think is not optimized.

Here is a picture of the story I told :)

[image]

Green then it became blue (font changed) :)

Comment: The text after `<span>` tag contains Korean Hangul characters instead of Japanese (both have different character sets). Probably the characters are rendered based on system font setting for Korean typography?

Comment: Can you try appending `yourString.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`?

Comment: @NibblyPig I tried but no success